# How to allocate memory to int (*a)[2]?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

How do I allocate memory to integer type (*a)[2] ? I am comfortable doing it with **a, *a etc. etc., also *a[2], but this looks different.

Can somebody help out ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `a`? How did you find yourself in this pickle?

Comment: Welcome to SO. :)  here on SO, you can *accept* an answer given to you, if it helped you. You get +2 rep points too. (we accept by clicking on the big empty V sign next to the answer). :)

Answer (score 3):

Same as for any pointer type, say you have

```
int (*a)[2];
```

a pointer `a` to arrays of 2 `int`, then you allocate

```
a = malloc(number_of_rows * sizeof *a);
```

to get a block of `number_of_rows * (2 * sizeof (int))` bytes.

You then access that with

```
a[i][j]
```

with `0 <= i < number_of_rows` and `0 <= j < 2`.

Comment: Very true, thank you. But how does casting really take place here ? - i think i can compare this with a struct now ?

Comment: What casting? The `void*` returned by `malloc` is implicitly converted to `int(*)[2]` for the assignment. The memory layout is as if you had an `int array[number_of_rows][2];` and then `a = &array;`. You can indeed compare it with `struct foo *bar; bar = malloc(number_of_rows * sizeof (struct foo));`, the `int[2]` is analogous to `struct foo` then.

Comment: Good answer; this is a trick I didn't know for making a 2D array, and it risks making my brain explode to think about it. In my experience some compilers will complain that the `void *` return type of `malloc` cannot be implicitly converted to another type, and require casting. How would you do that? `a = (int(*)[2])malloc()`?

Comment: I think its not getting converted. Also, the casting needs to be conveyed, (that is how can it be implicit), malloc needs to be told that somehow ... ?

Comment: Ah, those would be C++ compilers. Generally I would advise avoiding to compile C with C++ compilers if possible. But if you have to, then yes, you have gotten the cast exactly right.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Increased my knowledge of debugging hard pointers a bit. Thanks a lot guys.