# If my computer is a 32 bit system, it has a 32 bit address right? But when I print any memory address in C why do I get an address <32bit?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, format-specifiers

For example

```
printf("%u",&a);
```

gives me output

> 65524

which is a 16 bit address.

Comment: Not everybody can sit in the front row ... ;-)

Comment: 0x0000000000000000 is a 64bit address, isn't it? And it's equal 0x0.

Comment: "If my computer is a 32 bit system,it has a 32 bit address right?" Likely, but not guaranteed. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34725569/584518). Also, there is no guarantee that `unsigned int` will be 32 bits.

Comment: So if you print a variable and get the value `1` would that be a 1 bit variable? And the value `7` a 3 bit variable? No - you can't determine the number of bits available by printing the value. Use `sizeof`

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is your platform?

Comment: There's a difference between "shorter than 32 bit" and "smaller than  2^32-1"

Comment: @user3528438 - Not when printed with `%u` - you just can't see the number of zeros in front as they are not printed. So you can't tell the actual number of bits - the value may be representable in 16 bit variable but still come from a 32 bit variable.

Comment: A "32-bit system" typically refers to the natural width of the processor.  _not_ it addressing capability - which may be much wider or narrower.

Answer (score 4):

Because you used wrong format specifier which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To print a pointer, you should use `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `void*`. Something like

```
 printf("%p",(void *)&a);
```

will do the job.

That said, you should look into the concepts of [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) the first thing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Right. That's too broad to cover here, I've added a link, hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply answer your assumption about address size by checking the size of any pointer instead of a test variable's address:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int*));
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(float*));
```

Assuming that a byte in all systems equals eight bit, you can see about size of address.

Please see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914221/experiments-using-sizeof-with-arrays-and-pointers/37123062#37123062)

Answer (score 0):

To find the highest possible address for (most of) the currently common systems do this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  uintptr_t uip = (uintptr_t) -1;
  void * vp = (void*) uip;

  printf("%p\n", vp);
}
```